# Buttons and Time not operating

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I don't know whats wrong with the code as the buttons are not moving and timer is not working.

As the button is tricky to catch before 60sec as it should move the whole screen.

I tried with the code but the button is moving only once. I want the button to be moving always away when ever I place mouse arrow on it.

```
<SCRIPT>
    var lose = 'YOU LOST'
    var win = 'YOU WON'

    function finish(message) {
        clearTimeout(timer)
        output.innerHTML = message
        button1.style.display='none'
        button2.style.display='none'
        button3.style.display='none'
    }

    function moveme(obj) {
        obj.style.pixelLeft += Math.random() * 250 - 150
        obj.style.pixelTop += Math.random() * 250 - 150
    }
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="goldenred" TEXT="black" onSelectStart="return false">
    <CENTER> 
    <H1><b>Test</b></H1>
    <P>If you can't click this button, you r lost!<BR>You got 60 sec.!</P>
    <BR><BR>
    <INPUT
        TYPE=BUTTON
        ID=button1
        onClick="finish(win)"
        onMouseOver="this.style.position='absolute'; moveme(this)"
        VALUE="CLICK"
        STYLE="display:none; top:300; left:200"
    >
    <INPUT
        TYPE=BUTTON
        ID=button2
        onClick="finish(win)"
        onMouseOver="button1.style.display=''; button3.style.display=''; this.style.position='absolute'; moveme(this); timer = setTimeout('finish(lose)', 60000)"
        VALUE="CLICK"
        STYLE="top:300; left:200"
    >

    <INPUT
        TYPE=BUTTON
        ID=button3
        onClick="finish(win)"
        onMouseOver="this.style.position='absolute'; moveme(this)"
        VALUE="CLICK"
        STYLE="display:none; top:300; left:200"
    >

    <SPAN ID="output"></SPAN>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say its is because you are passing in 60 for the timeout interval, and the units are in millisecond, 60 milliseconds is pretty fast, no wonder it only works once, and I would say that finish function is running but is throwing an error, because what is output, can't see that variable defined anywhere

Comment: i done changing time to 60000ms. the ouput is the message as i dont want anyone to touch the button...